# FFmpeg DeckLink Windows 10, 64: "Incorrect codec parameters, No such device or address"

Tags: ffmpeg

I downloaded the latest static 
 [ffmpeg build](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/ffmpeg-3.2-win64-static.zip) which support decklink format (-f decklink) for Windows. 
I also installed  [the decklink 10.8.2 driver](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzEwkDOizqfcRy1CY2lMVnVtWHM) (it's the latest available driver when this build was published)

Please see the decklink devices:

> ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1 -i nullsrc -f decklink -list_devices 1 dummy

```
Input #0, lavfi, from 'nullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[decklink @ 0000000000733c00] Blackmagic DeckLink devices:
[decklink @ 0000000000733c00]   'DeckLink SDI (1)'
[decklink @ 0000000000733c00]   'DeckLink SDI (2)'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Immediate exit requestedStream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

And supported formats for the first device:

> ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1 -i nullsrc -f decklink -list_formats 1 "DeckLink
>   SDI (1)"

```
Input #0, lavfi, from 'nullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320] Supported formats for 'DeckLink SDI (1)':
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   1       720x486 at 30000/1001 fps (interlaced, lower field first)
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   2       720x486 at 24000/1001 fps
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   3       720x576 at 25000/1000 fps (interlaced, upper field first)
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   4       1920x1080 at 24000/1001 fps
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   5       1920x1080 at 24000/1000 fps
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   6       1920x1080 at 25000/1000 fps
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   7       1920x1080 at 30000/1001 fps
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   8       1920x1080 at 30000/1000 fps
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   9       1920x1080 at 25000/1000 fps (interlaced, upper field first)
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   10      1920x1080 at 30000/1001 fps (interlaced, upper field first)
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   11      1920x1080 at 30000/1000 fps (interlaced, upper field first)
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   12      1280x720 at 50000/1000 fps
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   13      1280x720 at 60000/1001 fps
[decklink @ 0000000000e03320]   14      1280x720 at 60000/1000 fps
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Immediate exit requestedStream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> rawvideo (native))
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

But with single quotes it didn't work(possibly it matters):

> ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1 -i nullsrc -f decklink -list_formats 1 'DeckLink
>   SDI (1)'

```
Input #0, lavfi, from 'nullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[NULL @ 0000000002687480] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'SDI'
SDI: Invalid argument
```

But when I tried the following command:

> ffmpeg -i RTMPsource -s 720x576 -r 25000/1000 -pix_fmt uyvy422 -f
>   decklink "Decklink SDI (1)"

```
ffmpeg version 3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.100 / 57. 64.100
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Metadata:
  duration              0.00
  width                 1024.00
  height                576.00
  videodatarate         2441.41
  framerate             25.00
  videocodecid          7.00
  audiodatarate         125.00
  audiosamplerate       48000.00
  audiosamplesize       16.00
  stereo                TRUE
  audiocodecid          10.00
  encoder               Lavf57.71.100
  filesize              0.00
[flv @ 00000000001c68a0] video stream discovered after head already parsed
[flv @ 00000000001c68a0] audio stream discovered after head already parsed
Input #0, flv, from 'RTMPsource':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1024x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such device or addressStream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

I got the next error: **"Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such device or address"**

Can please someone explain what is the reason of this error and any way to fix it?

Comment: Run `ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1 -i nullsrc -f decklink -list_devices 1 dummy` to see the list of **output** Decklink devices. And then `ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 1 -i nullsrc -f decklink -list_formats 1 'device name'`

Comment: @Mulvya Hi, I updated the question with necessary info. I think the device name and the format parameters are correct. Can you please check, possibly I missed something.

Comment: In your playout command, device name is `"Decklink SDI (1)"`, but the exact string is `"DeckLink SDI (1)"` (capital L). Try with that.